# How to avoid exposing internal database primary keys for an entity in a REST call

Tags: java, rest, database-design, guid, uniqueidentifier

How to avoid exposing internal database primary keys for an entity in a REST call using a backend API built using Spring Boot framework

```
public class Order {

    private Long id;
    private String uniqId; // say a GUID
    // other attributes 
}
```

We are currently exposing the following API calls

```
POST /api/v1/orders
GET /api/v1/orders/<order_id>
GET api/v1/orders - list call
```

We don't want to expose the primary key of the Order to the user interface layer or to external API users who will consume this API. Does that mean we should modify the API interfaces to perform lookup based on uniq_id instead something like as follows and use the primary key (order.id) only for FK reference

```
GET /api/v1/orders/<order_uniq_id>
```

How best to expose the API calls here and construct the database schema for Order entity

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se in exposing the primary key from your API.  Why do you think there is something wrong with this?

Comment: ...how can a caller refer to its order without a PK?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it would be easier for someone to guess the sequence and try to randomly pull data for a different tenant

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is it better to use a primary key based on a Long or GUID as a primary key

Comment: It really depends on a few things.  A UUID would make sense if you wanted to make the primary key not only unique within its table but also unique within the entire database or system.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen UUID has performance issues, hence we went with Long

Comment: That is fine; you should probably only use a UUID if long does not satisfy all requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use access control and don't send the order ID to users and clients who have nothing to do with it. Exposing the PK is perfectly fine, but if you don't want to do it, then use a secondary key or a bunch of properties which are unique to the order, for example the user id and the timestamp.

Comment: which timestamp are you referring to? how can user + timestamp be easier for the end user

Comment: @Rpj I did not say it is easier for anybody to use anything else than the PK, but it is possible to solve the problem without it. As of the "it would be easier for someone to guess the sequence and try to randomly pull data for a different tenant" comment, it looks like you never heard of access control. Just send JWT or credentials in Authorization header, check permissions like everybody does and problem solved.